# Get average number from SQL statement

Tags: mysql, average

I've got a SQL statement:

```
SELECT AVG(`totalhours`)/5 AS `average`,* FROM `report_signout` JOIN `employee` ON `employee`.`username`=`report_signout`.`username`
```

However it's not working. Basically I need to calculate the average total hours an employee has been on the premises in any one week, the assumption is accepted that the office is only open 5 days a week. The total hours are coming from the table `report_signout` which I need to join on the `username` of the `employee` table so I can produce an outcome where I can then list the Firstname and Lastname of the employee along with the average hours on a web page. That last part is done in PHP which I already know how to do. I just need to see where I'm going wrong with the SQL statement.

If someone could point out to me please or give me a bit of help it would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 2):

MySQL does not really know what `totalhours` is. As you are referencing more than one table, a table is *not assumed*, so you need to declare what to average by defining the reference as:

```
`table name`.`column name`
```

This is true for most if not all MySQL built in functions. Use absolute declarations (ie those with table and column names both defined, as above) as much as possible.

```
SELECT AVG(`report_signout`.`totalhours`)/5 AS `average`,  
`report_signout`.*, `employee`.* 
FROM `report_signout` 
INNER JOIN `employee` ON `employee`.`username` = `report_signout`.`username`
```

---

As a small aside, try and avoid vague `JOIN` referencing instead using a complete JOIN reference, which states the *type* of JOIN rather than an assumption.

Also try to avoiding using `*` selection instead stating each column you wish to call.

Comment: @Dave if that solves your issue you can click the tick next to the question, cheers :)

Comment: @Dave If you feel this answer helped solved your issue, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This will help the community to keep the focus on unanswered questions.